# ! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble

Tags: latex, tex

I have some legacy batch file that generates a PDF with LaTeX. There is a main.tex file which "includes"  multiple *.tex files as subpages.
In the main `.tex` file I already have declared `\usepackage{float}`.
When executing the batch which launches the generation of the PDF I get the error:
`! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option 'H'.`

Adding the `\usepackage{float}` before the `\begin{document}` in the file where the problem comes from throws the error:
`! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you provide more detail about the document construction? How are the "multiple `.tex` files included? Do you a main `.tex` file that `\include`s the other `.tex` files? That main file should have a preamble with the `document` environment - `\documentclass` ... `\begin{document}` ... `\end{document}`. Do you have `\usepackage{float}` between `\documentclass` and `\end{document}`?

Comment: @Werner The `.tex` files are included using `\subfile{texFileName}`. The maine `.tex` file has a `\begin{document}` and a `\end{document}` and before the `\begin{document}` there is a `\usepackage{float}` declaration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replacing `.*}[H]` with `.*}[h!]` fixed the problem.

Comment: This does not make sense given the problem description.

Comment: @Werner Doesn't make sense the fact that I replaced the float option `H` with `h!`?

Comment: Yes, the problem seems unrelated to that change, since `H` should exist (you're loading [`float`](//ctan.org/pkg/float) already).

Comment: @Werner Then I really have no idea, I found this solution on some forum and apparently it worked, so I don't really mind, but if you have other solution, I'd gladly try it out.